# Dimension of the zero locus of a single holomorphic function

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $M$ be a non-compact complex manifold of complex dimension $m$. 
As an example, one can let $M = \mathbb{C}^m$, with coordinates $z_1,\cdots,z_m$. "Usually", given a holomorphic $f$ function on $M$, you would expect $\{f=0\}$ to have codimension 1, i.e. to have dimension $m-1$. However, there are some degenerate cases:

A) trivially, if $f=0$, then $\{f=0\}$ is all of $M$. This case can be easily ruled out by requiring $f$ not to vanish identically.

B) there are examples where $\{f=0\}$ could be empty. This is the case if for instance $M = \mathbb{C}^m$, and we let
$f(z_1,\cdots,z_m) = e^{z_1+\cdots+z_m}$.

Are there other possible degenerate cases than A) and B)? In other words, if $f$ does not vanish identically, but does vanish at some point in $M$, then is it necessarily the case that $\{f=0\}$ has dimension $m-1$?

Edit: If $\partial f \neq 0$ at some point $p$ in $\{f=0\}$, then the dimension of $\{f=0\}$ in a neighborhood of $p$ is indeed $m-1$, by the holomorphic version of the implicit function theorem. Hence in this case, there is a non-empty open subset of $M$ of dimension $m-1$. But then I just realized I have an issue. What is the definition of dimension for a singular analytic space? This is I am sure in Grauert's work. In the case where $\partial f \neq 0$ at some point $p$ in $\{f=0\}$, does it follow that the dimension of $\{f=0\}$ is $m-1$? It would then remain to consider the case where $\partial f$ vanishes identically on $\{f=0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is a connected complex manifold of dimension $m$ and $f\in \mathcal O(M)$ is a non zero, non-invertible holomorphic function, then the zero set of $f$  **always** has codimension one: $$\operatorname {dim}Z(f)=m-1$$ **Remarks**
1) The function $f$ is invertible if and only if it nowhere vanishes.
Non-zero constants or your $e^{z_1+\cdots+z_m}$ are examples of invertible functions.
2) The result is valid for $M$ compact, but in a vacuous sense: every holomorphic  $f$ is constant and thus zero or invertible!
3) The result is false for a non smooth complex analytic space.
For example, take   $M=Z(z_1\cdot z_2)\subset \mathbb C^2$ (the union of the coordinate axes) and $f=z_2$.
That function is neither zero nor invertible, but nevertheless $Z(f)$  is of dimension $1$ although $M$ has dimension $1$ too.

Comment: Thank you! I was just a little shaky because I did not know how to define the notion of dimension for $\{f=0\}$, which could in general contain singularities.

Comment: Dear Malkoun, the singularities of $Z(f)=\{f=0\}$ do not matter at all. What matters is that $M$ has **no** singularities, i.e. is a manifold rather than an arbitrary complex space.

Comment: Yes, I understand. And I like your example about the union of the $z_1$ and $z_2$ axes.